# Post selected items to table

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have a results list produced by a search. Each item has a check box. What I want to do is post the selected items to a different table.

Here is the code that displays the data:

```
        <section class="grid_12">
        <div class="block-border">
        <form class="block-content form" id="table_form" method="post" action="">
            <h1>Sortable table</h1>

            <table id="mylist" data-campaignId="<?=$campaignid?>" class="table sortable no-margin" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="black-cell"><span class="loading"></span></th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <span class="column-sort">
                                <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                                <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                            </span>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">Client Of</th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <span class="column-sort">
                                <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                                <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                            </span>
                            Home Phone
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <span class="column-sort">
                                <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                                <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                            </span>
                            Email
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <span class="column-sort">
                                <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                                <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                            </span>
                            Created On
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="table-actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <?php foreach($r->result() as $row) : ?>
                    <tr data-clientid="$row->id"> 
                      <td class="th table-check-cell">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" class="checkbox">
                      </td>
                        <td><a href="/client/view/<?=$row->id?>"><?=$row->firstname?> <?=$row->lastname?></a></td>
                        <td><ul class="keywords">
                            <li><a href="#"><?=$row->clientof?></a></li>
                            <li class="orange-keyword"><a href="#"><?=$row->status?></a></li>
                        </ul></td>
                        <td><?=$row->homephone?></td>
                        <td><?=$row->email?></td>
                        <td><?=$row->created?></td>
                        <td class="table-actions">
                            <a href="/client/view/<?=$row->id?>" title="View / Edit" class="with-tip"><img src="/images/icons/fugue/pencil.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                </tbody>

            </table>

            <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="block-footer">
                <img src="images/icons/fugue/arrow-curve-000-left.png" width="16" height="16" class="picto"> 
                <a href="javascript:toggleChecked('checked')" class="button">Select All</a> 
                <a href="javascript:toggleChecked('')" class="button">Unselect All</a>
                <span class="sep"></span>
                <button id="post_diff_table">POST selected</button>
            </div>                  
        </form></div>
    </section>
```

Here is all the current javascript in the above page.

```
<? $campaignid = $this->uri->segment(4); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
toggleChecked = function(status)
{
    alert('trigger');
    $(".checkbox").each( function() {
        $(this).attr("checked",status);
    });
}
});
//-->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#post_diff_table').click(function() {
var table = $('table#mylist');
var campagnid = table.data('campaignId');
//Array of checked client ids
var checked_clients = $.map(table.find('tr td.table-check-cell input:checked'), function(e) {
    return $(e).parents('tr').data('clientid');
});
if (checked_clients.length === 0) {return false;}
//call the controller
$.post('/ajaxmodals/campaign_post_to_other_table', {
    campagnid: campagnid,
    clients: checked_clients
}, function(data) {
    //process response
},"json");
});​});
</script>
```

Here is the code in ajax controller.

```
function campaign_post_to_other_table()
{
$campagnid=$this->input->post('campagnid');
/* @var Array */
$clients = $this->input->post('clients');
foreach ($clients as $client_id) {
        $clientid = $this->input->post('clientid');
        $submit['clientid'] = $clientid;
        $submit['campaignid'] = $this->input->post('campaignid');
        $submit['creationdate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $submit['createdby'] = $this->session->userdata('uid');
        //print_r($submit); exit();

        $newid = $this->campaign_model->add_user_to_campaign($submit);
        $cname = $this->client_model->get_client_name($clientid);

        echo json_encode(array("response"=>"Success","name"=>$cname,"id"=>$newid,"clientid"=>$clientid));
  }
  }
```

Here is the add_user_to_campaign model.

```
function add_user_to_campaign($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('campaign_to_client',$data);

    $newid = $this->db->insert_id();
    return $newid;
}
```

Comment: by post you mean to update different sql table ?

Comment: as i always say - *do not generate javascript with php*.

Comment: show the table header, to understand which row is what

Comment: yes it post to a different table

Comment: thanks for helping. The table i am posting to has this header:         

id

campaignid

clientid

creationdate

createdby

modifieddate

Comment: the table you reading from you should refactor it to make good js/jquery code. now it terrible :)

Comment: I think I can use function campaign_subscriber_add() if I adjust the javascript above...maybe???

Comment: do you avare of client side and server side scripting ?

Comment: just show the head of the table you posted first in your question (edit question)

Comment: I am not sure what your question is.

Comment: your generated page have `<table>` element, show me content of `<th>` element (OO only dao kills mind) better to show generated page,

Comment: ok I made edit and provided th

Comment: ok last question, campaign id is the same for whole table ?

Comment: What is the problem? Is there any error?

Comment: @feela this will not work, composing answer now

Comment: campaignid...all i can see is that it shows in the url like this.../admin/campaign/view/2

Comment: i can also see it as a value in view source

Comment: @feela any help here please?

Answer (score 0):

In table definition (I assume that $campaignid is campaignid, change mylist to whatever you want):

```
<table id="mylist" data-campaignId="<?=$campaignid?>" class="table sortable no-margin" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

In your loop set data for client

```
<?php foreach($r->result() as $row) : ?>
    <tr data-clientid="$row->id"> 
      <td class="th table-check-cell">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" class="checkbox">
      </td>
      <!---other td here -->
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
<!--button to post all selected items -->
<button id="post_diff_table">POST selected</button>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
$('#post_diff_table').click(function() {
    var table = $('table#mylist');
    var campagnid = table.data('campaignId');
    //Array of checked client ids
    var checked_clients = $.map(table.find('tr td.table-check-cell input:checked'), function(e) {
        return $(e).parents('tr').data('clientid');
    });
    if (checked_clients.length === 0) {return false;}
    //call the controller
    $.post('/ajaxmodals/campaign_post_to_other_table', {
        campagnid: campagnid,
        clients: checked_clients
    }, function(data) {
        //process response
    },"json");
});​});
```

in controller:

```
function campaign_post_to_other_table()
{
   $campagnid=$this->input->post('campagnid');
   /* @var Array */
   $clients = $this->input->post('clients');
   foreach ($clients as $client_id) {
     /* sql insertion code here 
        or call  $this->campaign_model->add_user_to_campaign for each clientid
     */
   }
}
```

The answer is not the copy-pastable code, as i have no idea of your project internals, but you should get the idea.

---

---

the suggestions on other code: do not do this in js:

```
$.post('/ajaxmodals/campaign_subscriber_add', { 
            clientid : cid,
            campaignid : <?=$r->id?>
```

get the campaignid from table data as in my sample

---

do not do this:

`$("#subscriberList").append('<li id="'+data.id+'"><a href="/client/view/'+data.clientid+'">'+data.name+'</a><span style="display: inline; float: right" onclick="javascript:delete_subscriber(\''+data.id+'\')">delete</span></li>');`

compose element in js, add event handlers, etc. your way make you to use to much global functions and make the code unreadable.

Comment: almost same as you do in your `else` block of `campaign_subscriber_add()`

Comment: I get error undefined variable campaignid...I will not give up...thanks for all the help and I will reward answer to you because I think if I work through it all I can get it to work.

Comment: ah I think you missed $campaignid in table def, you should place here real var, i just not know what is it, may be $r->id ?

Comment: also only way I could figure out how to get campaignid was this <? $campagnid = $this->uri->segment(4); ?> ...i do a print and it is correct.

Comment: > nope no erros...just does not insert data
data transfered ? the real way to insert data is unknown for me, it is your project

Comment: I just made edit above and provided rendered html source if that helps

Comment: what I am trying to do is add the selected clients to my email list. All campaignID is same for all. After I add them i want to return to this page: /admin/campaign/view/2#&tab-list to show newly added subscribers. No need for ajax if it is not possible.

Comment: changed in answer `<tr data-clientid="$row->id">`, `var checked_clients = $.map(table.find('tr td.table-check-cell input:checked'), function(e) {` it tuns that data ignores uppercasng

Comment: I just made edit above with all current code exactly how I have it. Can you please look it over and see where I am going wrong? Thanks man.

Comment: did you changed clientid as i described above ?

Comment: yes i did...still no insert...what would it take for you to take a look?

Comment: I also supplied model above for insert

Comment: get this php error --> Trying to get property of non-object before i even make selection and submit

Comment: i think i know what that error is. It is trying to get their email address but some do not have them.