# php insert checked items to mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I need help with this. I want to submit only checked off items to mysql table.

Here is html rendered from php page:

```
<table id="mylist" data-campaignId="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
        <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="92" class="checkbox"></td>
      <td><a href="/client/view/92">Bob</a></td>
      <td><ul class="keywords">
          <li><a href="#">Peter T</a></li>
          <li class="orange-keyword"><a href="#">New Lead</a></li>
        </ul></td>
      <td>(555) 555-5555</td>
      <td>dad@msn.com.com</td>
      <td>2011-03-21</td>
      <td class="table-actions"><a href="/client/view/92" title="View / Edit" class="with-tip"><img src="/images/icons/fugue/pencil.png" width="16" height="16"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="1074" class="checkbox"></td>
      <td><a href="/client/view/1074">Elinda Canty</a></td>
      <td><ul class="keywords">
          <li><a href="#">Mary</a></li>
          <li class="orange-keyword"><a href="#">New Lead</a></li>
        </ul></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>mary@live.com</td>
      <td>2011-06-29</td>
      <td class="table-actions"><a href="/client/view/1074" title="View / Edit" class="with-tip"><img src="/images/icons/fugue/pencil.png" width="16" height="16"></a></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<button id="add_users_to_campaign">Add Selected to Subscribers</button>
```

Here is complete souce of page.

```
<? $campaignid = $this->uri->segment(4); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
toggleChecked = function(status)
{

$(".checkbox").each( function() {
    $(this).attr("checked",status);
});
}
});
-->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#add_users_to_campaign').click(function() {
var campaignId = $("#mylist").attr("data-campaignId");
var clientid = [];
$("#mylist :checked").each(function() {
    clientid.push($(this).closest("tr").attr("data-clientid"));
});
if (clientid.length === 0) {
    return;
}
console.log(campaignId, clientid);
$.post('/ajaxmodels/add_users_to_campaign', {
    campaignId: campaignId,
    "clientid[]": clientid
}, function(data) {}, "json");
});
});​
</script>

<!-- Content -->
<article class="container_12">

<section class="grid_12">
    <div class="block-border">
    <?
    $attributes = array('class' => 'block-content form', 'id' => 'table_form');
    echo form_open('', $attributes);
    ?>
        <h1>Search Fields</h1>
        <div class="columns">
            <p class="colx4-left">
                <label>Find</label>
                <?php echo form_dropdown('quicksearch',$qs_array,'','class="full-width"');?>
            </p>
            <p class="colx4-mid">
                <label>Where</label>
                <?php echo form_dropdown('where',$where_array,'','class="full-width"');?>
            </p>
            <p class="colx4-center">
                <label>Search</label>
                <?php echo form_input('searchfor','','class="full-width"');?>
            </p>
            <p class="colx4-right">
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    <? echo form_close(); ?></div>
</section>

<section class="grid_12">
    <div class="block-border">
    <form class="block-content form" id="table_form" method="post" action="">
        <h1>Sortable table</h1>

        <table id="mylist" data-campaignId="<?=$campaignid?>" class="table sortable no-margin" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="black-cell"><span class="loading"></span></th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <span class="column-sort">
                            <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                            <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                        </span>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">Client Of</th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <span class="column-sort">
                            <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                            <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                        </span>
                        Home Phone
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <span class="column-sort">
                            <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                            <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                        </span>
                        Email
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <span class="column-sort">
                            <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                            <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                        </span>
                        Created On
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" class="table-actions">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <?php foreach($r->result() as $row) : ?>
                <tr>" 
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?=$row->id?>" class="checkbox">
                  </td>
                    <td><a href="/client/view/<?=$row->id?>"><?=$row->firstname?> <?=$row->lastname?></a></td>
                    <td><ul class="keywords">
                        <li><a href="#"><?=$row->clientof?></a></li>
                        <li class="orange-keyword"><a href="#"><?=$row->status?></a></li>
                    </ul></td>
                    <td><?=$row->homephone?></td>
                    <td><?=$row->email?></td>
                    <td><?=$row->created?></td>
                    <td class="table-actions">
                        <a href="/client/view/<?=$row->id?>" title="View / Edit" class="with-tip"><img src="/images/icons/fugue/pencil.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>

        </table>

        <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="block-footer">
            <img src="images/icons/fugue/arrow-curve-000-left.png" width="16" height="16" class="picto"> 
            <a href="javascript:toggleChecked('checked')" class="button">Select All</a> 
            <a href="javascript:toggleChecked('')" class="button">Unselect All</a>
            <span class="sep"></span>
            <button id="add_users_to_campaign">POST selected</button>
        </div>                  
    </form></div>
</section>
</article><!-- End Content -->
```

I want to insert only checked items to this table:

ID - auto increment

campaignid

clientid

creationdate

How can I do this?

I also need to avoid duplicate insert of clientid into same campaignid. So if the clientid already exist for this campaignid then skip insert.

Here is the function that i currently have in controller ajaxmodels:

```
function add_users_to_campaign(){
$campagnid=$this->input->post('campaignid');
$client = $this->input->post('client');
    foreach ($client as $client_id) {
        $submit['clientid'] = $clientid;
        $submit['campaignid'] = $this->input->post('campaignid');
        $submit['creationdate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $submit['createdby'] = $this->session->userdata('uid');
        $newid = $this->campaign_model->add_user_to_campaign($submit);

    }
}
```

Here is the campaign_model->add_user_to_campaign

```
function add_user_to_campaign($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('campaign_to_client',$data);

    $newid = $this->db->insert_id();
    return $newid;
}
```

When I check off an item and submit the page refreshes with no errors and I get nothing inserted.

Comment: Where is the information coming from - for example `campaignid`, `clientid` and `creationdate`?

Comment: info is coming a php search results page. creationdate will just be the current date it is inserted (timestamp).

Comment: i tried this but the help got way to complex for me so i simplified my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897179/post-selected-items-to-table

Comment: first add a the value property to check box and also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Salman took your advice but now what?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all four in the first instance (i.e. to get you head around it), try just the one row in the table and see if that works.

Also you should consider not using the same names of each of the items. i.e. use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[1]" class="checkbox" value="yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[92]" class="checkbox" value="yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[1024]" class="checkbox" value="yes">
```

**EDIT**

The data back from a form in in pairs (i.e. name,value). The name needs to be unique. But yours is not. You have three names with value `selected[]` and having different (potentially) values. How do you tell them apart?

My first paragraph was to explain how it is best to go about debugging (first make it simple then add more complications.

**FURTHER EDIT**

I have added the value bit in to the above.

Or you can do this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" class="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" class="checkbox" value="92">
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" class="checkbox" value="1024">
```

**MICKEY MOUSE EXAMPLE**

PHP first

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>

The forms data
<?php
$selector = $_GET['selector'];
print_r($selector);
echo "Now go through than data\n";

foreach ($selector as $name=>$value)
{
    // Find the name
    $character = $_GET["id$name"];

    echo "$character is $name or $value depends on the method you chose\n";
}
echo "\n\nThose are the checked ones";
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Wibble</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="send.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="id0" value="client Joe Bloggs">
<input type="hidden" name="id1" value="Client Bugs Bunny">
<input type="hidden" name="id2" value="Client Al Capone ">
Check 1 <input type="checkbox" name="selector[]" value="1">
Check 80 <input type="checkbox" name="selector[]" value="80">
Check 200 <input type="checkbox" name="selector[]" value="200">
<input type="submit" value="depends">
</form>
<form action="send.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="id1" value="client Joe Bloggs">
<input type="hidden" name="id80" value="Client Bugs Bunny">
<input type="hidden" name="id200" value="Client Al Capone ">
Check 1 <input type="checkbox" name="selector[1]" value="yes">
Check 80 <input type="checkbox" name="selector[80]" value="yes">
Check 200 <input type="checkbox" name="selector[200]" value="yes">
<input type="submit" value="otherway">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dev - I added property value of clientid and made edit above. Ed thanks but i read that the selected has to be just like it is to somehow check it to see if it is selected???

Comment: -1 every thing above the "further edit" line. In fact, -1 for everything below that line as well.

Comment: Salman A - Why not give an answer yourself. The name/value pairs need to be unique. BTW - The question has been edited a lot from the original.

Comment: Ed it has to be in my function...i am just not grasping this...my insert is wrong...grrrrr...hit head on wall here ->Brick Wall

Comment: See above (again) - It is a simple example that should give you pointers on how to do it. (need to add checking etc). Add Javascript at a later stage.

Comment: Ed i appreciate your time but i have no clue what you are trying to give me as an answer to my question?

Comment: @smitty - I though the question was to link a check box with other details. The Mickey mouse example does that. Perhaps put it into your web server and give it a go. As to the function bit - that is easy. Just get a simple example to work first (i.e. print stuff out) and then build on that. Javascript is not required at this stage.

Comment: BTW `tr data-clientId="1074"` is not form data

Comment: i think var checked_client takes care of that doesn't it?

Comment: Ed - the question was how to insert data of selected items into a mysql table.

Comment: @Smitty - Have you got the data to form the actual query. It appears that this is not the case. Why try to run when you are having difficulties in walking. Take a large cake - eat it slice be slice - the problem of eating a whole cake will seem simpler.

Comment: @Ed do I really need all the hidden fields?

Comment: @smity - You could look them up from your database instead.